# Branching and merging my github remote repo

Tags: git, github, merge, repository, git-remote

I am quiet new to git and github. I have a team of 4 working on a project and have set up a remote repo in github. We have been pushing to the master branch for several weeks now. I want to know how to push to a test branch and later after reviewing merge it to the master when finalized. Can someone help?

I have tried creating a test branch and merging it with the master and it messed up the whole history. It says the master is behind the test by 'n' commits and this doesn't seem right.

Comment: make sure you're merging test into master, and not merging master into test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, from the command line, make sure your master branch is up-to-date locally:

   `git checkout master`
2. Create a new local branch named `feature/test`:

   `git checkout -b feature/test`
3. Make changes to some files.
4. Tell Git to track the changes you made to your files - repeat this step to add all of the changed files:

   `git add (path to file that was changed)`
5. Create a commit with all your changes:

   `git commit -m "a message about your commit"`
6. Push this set of changes to a `feature/test` branch on your team Github:

   `git push origin feature/test`
7. Now, create a Pull Request via the GitHub UI: Click on the `Pull Requests` tab, click `New pull request`. Choose `master` as the Base branch and `feature/test` as the Compare branch, then click `Create pull request`.
8. You'll now see a pull request created for your test branch, which your team can comment on. To make further changes based on feedback, just repeat steps 3-6 and the Pull Request will automatically be updated with your changes.
9. When you're satisfied with the changes, click the Merge button to commit your changes to the `master` branch.

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked fine and the branches are now in order

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way,
The concept is, your master branch is full proof. The best practice is, create branches from **master** every time you are working for a new feature.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b feature1 -- This will create new branch from master
```

Now all of your members will push to the corresponding feature branch. After that, you will merge the feature branches into master.

Another thing you can do is,

Revoke the permission of the members to commit to master branches. Each member will have their own forked repo of Master. They can create their own branches for a feature. After all the code is done, they can give a pull request to the Upstream Master branch.

There are tons of way to manage your situation. But, at the very beginning, you can start with any one of the above-mentioned ways.